# VSCode hot reload for flutter

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I've just started playing with Flutter in VSCode. I also installed the Dart Plugin.
Running the demo app I read in the terminal 
[image]

Is this the only way to hot-reload the app? I mean I should always keep the terminal open and focus on it to type "r" in order to reload my views?
Isn't there a shortcut directly from VSCode?

Comment: I had hot reloading working with Save on Windows 10 (Ctrl-S) in the 32-bit version of VSCode (1.31.1), but when I uninstalled the 32-bit version (retaining extensions and settings) and installed the 64-bit version (1.32.1) I lost this ability. All of the settings are correct, and even after restarting the OS and application and uninstalling and re-installing the extensions, 64-bit VSCode does not hot reload on Save. It *does* hot reload on Restart however (the green counter-clockwise arrow or Ctrl-Shift-F5). This appears to be a fairly new issue specific to the 1.32.1 release: https://github.c

Comment: If you run the code in Debugging mode then you don't have to press r for it to trigger hot reload.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There's an extension for that. Called `Dart Code` and another one named `Flutter Code`

They will detect that your project is a Dart/Flutter project. And allows you to debug it + hot reload using f5.

Comment: that works for the `r` functionality...anyone knows how to do a complete reload (`R`) from vs code?

Comment: oh...just found it (https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/411). there is a command that you can use (`Flutter: full restart`)

Comment: You can also use Ctrl+F5 for a full restart during debugging :-)

Comment: There is a setting `dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave` to enable hot reload on save for Flutter apps in Visual Studio Code. You need to start the app in debug mode for this to work, Debug -> Start Debugging.

Comment: @apaatsio There is no setting like that.

Comment: @atilkan See https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartflutterhotreloadonsave

Comment: @apaatsio It did not work for me, i opened an issue. Confirmed it was a bug.

Answer (score 59):

For **2023**, this solution worked.

**Steps**

1. Open Settings.
2. Paste this text > **`dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave`** on the settings search box.
3. And change value from "**Manual**" to "**All**"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This works, just make sure you run/debug the app using VSCode's built-in debugger, rather than just executing `flutter run` in the integrated terminal.

Comment: That worked for me, one thing is, the pop up keeps on coming at the bottom whenever I do ctrl+s regarding the hot reload, could it be made hidden?

Comment: In my case i don't want the HR when save, the option for me is Never

Answer (score 16):

If you like to hot reload your app with a keybinding better than Ctrl+Shift+F5, just change the Debug: Restart to Ctrl+S, so whenever you trigger the the Ctrl+S the app will first save your changes according to the workbench.action.files.save and afterwards restart the app (=hot reload, it is the green circle you see in the debugbar).

Keybindings for VS Code:

[image: Screenshot of keybindings for vs code]

Answer (score 9):

VSCode debug -> `start debuging`, make a change and try, That's what you want.

Answer (score 6):

No idea why F5 does not hot reload for me :(

But, you can map the -

```
Flutter: Hot Reload
```

command to whatever key combo floats your boat via -

```
Preferences > Keyboard ShortCuts
```

as in this screenshot -

[image]

Comment: The default Shortcut for "Hot Reload" in VS Code is Ctrl + F5 for me.

Answer (score 5):

open the Debug sidebar from VSCode and use it

[image]

then when you save, it will hot reload and apply the changes you make
that is what working with me

Comment: I noticed this today (And working great). I'm new to Flutter and some programming in general, but was wondering if there are any drawbacks from developing via the debugger verses running the app from something like "flutter run"? Is it common practice to develop entirely via running the debugger? I know its running from a launch.json file; so was wondering if there would be any side effects when trying to deploy the app or something?...

Answer (score 3):

on Mac select

> Run without Debugging or Shift+f5

you will see this at top select the electric icon for Hot Reload.

[image: Hot Reload Bar]

After doing some changes save it. It will auto reflect changes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run Flutter app from VS Code's built-in debugger not VS Code's terminal.

Answer (score 2):

use the **green reload** button **to hot reload** the app in VS Code

Comment: What to do to if those buttons don't appear anywhere in VS Code? I'm trying to find that whole panel of buttons, but it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: take a look at the official doc for support [link]https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code

Answer (score 2):

**===== Aug 2022 UPDATE =====**

v3.42 and above: You can enable hot reload on autosave in the latest version by setting *Flutter Hot Reload On Save* to `allIfDirty` in your VSCode settings.

**===== Old Versions (Early 2022 and below) =====**

**v3.41 and below:** You can enable hot reload on autosave in the latest version by setting `Flutter Hot Reload On Save` to `always` in your VSCode settings.

**v3.19 only:**  They disabled hot reload on autosave completely.

**v3.18 and below:**  The extension hot reloads automatically when auto saving.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Setting]

if flutter and dart extensions already installed on vscode

Set from manual to All

Comment: in IntelliJ IDEA exist this option?

Answer (score 1):

yes Here is the plugin Dart Code for VS CODE

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code

here is official doc for VsCode flutter

https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/#vscode

Answer (score 1):

In VS once installed Dart + Flutter extension, 2 options to hot reload 1) Use combo keys Command + Shift + F5. 2) Save the file by use combo keys Command + S

Comment: What key do you mean by "Command" ? Not everyone is using an Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have both extensions and VSCode is set to Hot Reload once a document is saved. The only time I can reload my app is by stopping and restarting my debugger

Answer (score 1):

i dont know why but my vscode hot reloading not work if you have this problem you can use `ctrl + f5` to refresh app.
hope to work for developers that hot reloading not work for them.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Run Hot Reload picture]

Select ▷ then "Run without Debugging" -> You can now use ⌘S on Mac to ⚡ Hot Reload ⚡

Answer (score 1):

If you run your flutter project from the terminal you will have to manually press `r` to do a hot reload.

Therefore use the `Run and Debug` option in the VS Code to test your project.

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter problems with Hot Reload due to VS Code issues like [this](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1262#issuecomment-471452938), which is relevant while writing this answer.

The most convincing way I see to do it without downgrading, updating to Insiders builds and/or loosing dev speed is to use the green restart/reload button in the VS Code run widget or `Ctrl+Shift+F5` shortcut, but this option may be inacceptable for projects with trickier navigation and few different views.

Answer (score 0):

If you want enabled hot reload in flutter project you need to enable auto save in file>autosave in vscod IDE

Answer (score 0):

Use these settings and same settings add User tap bar

[image: Hot Reload Issue Fix follower This settings]