# Hot Restart (previously Full restart) in Flutter VS Code whilst debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Whilst running my app using `flutter run` in the console I can press 'r' to do a reload and press 'R' to do a reload and restart.  Is there a way to do this whilst debugging in VS Code?  Saving a file causes a hot reload but I can't figure out a way to do a full restart.

**Edit**

This is a little bit different to the hot reload option so I don't think this is a duplicate.  This question regards performing a full restart of the application without reinstalling it.  This is possible by pressing a capital R in the console, as opposed to pressing a lowercase r in the console which would perform a hot reload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode hot reload for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210769/vscode-hot-reload-for-flutter)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When debugging you can press `Ctrl`+`F5` for a full restart, or you can run the `Flutter: Full Restart` command from the VS Code's command palette (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` or `Cmd`+`Shift`+`P` for macOS).

Note: In the next version (v2.13.0, which there's a beta of available) "Full Restart" has been renamed to "Hot Restart" to better reflect how it works (this is happening across the other Flutter tools and docs too).

Related info:

- [Flutter VS Code docs](https://flutter.io/using-ide-vscode/)
- [Dart Code keybindings](https://dartcode.org/docs/key-bindings/)
- [Dart Code debugging commands](https://dartcode.org/docs/debugging-commands/)

Comment: perfect :-) the command pallette seems to be what I was missing most

Comment: It's super useful! Makes it really fast to do so many things without need keybindings for them all! It also shows the key-bindings for things that have them, so a good way to learn them while you're still using the palette to run stuff :)

Answer (score 5):

The chosen answer wasn't working for me with Flutter 1.2.1 so I used this solution:

1. get the [Flutter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter)
2. search for `dart.flutterDebuggerRestartBehaviour` in VS Code settings and set it to `hotRestart`
3. start the debugger (F5) and click the restart button when you want to hot restart:

   [image]

Comment: Upvoted for your trick. But, another question is "how to manage the `hotReload`?"

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, my English is not so good. I mean, if we use `dart.flutterDebuggerRestartBehaviour = hotRestart` then how do I do the` hotReload` action. Because the `hotRestart` process will redirect us to the start page of the application.

Comment: FYI, its not 'Flutter 1.2.1' problem, but VSCode. This problem appears after I have upgraded to version 1.32,

Comment: I see. In my case I just save the file and the reload-level changes are reflected on the device.

Comment: +1 for this another trick. Since I've disabled the `Flutter Hot Reload on save`  feature, then I am never thought this will work. Thank you very much, dude.