# How to solve the problem of Flutter hot reload

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

My flutter project is working properly on my android device. When I delete default code and save then hot reload is not working. It does not show any error at the terminal. I am using vs code editor and connected via data cable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode hot reload for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210769/vscode-hot-reload-for-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common causes for hot reload appearing not to work are things like modifying your main method (hot reload does not re-run this). Check what you're doing against the limitations listed in the docs at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload

Things that don't hot reload include:

- `static` fields
- changes to `main` method
- changes to `initState`
- enums changed to classes and vice-versa
- generic type args modified