# Sending "r" to the terminal and saving the file as I hit "Ctrl + S"

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+s",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "workbench.action.files.save"
        ],
        "text": "r"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

here's the code in keybindings.json of vscode, but it is not working as expected!
Just saving the file and not sending "r" to the terminal

I tried everything and I just want it to do both

1. save the file
2. send r to terminal

Comment: why do  you need to send r to terminal tho?

Comment: to reload the app

Comment: Can you use a file watcher like chokidar instead?

Comment: ...actually I remember there was extention to run things on file save

Comment: Would https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave work for you?

Comment: i hope it would work, but where to put my code, I'm sorry for asking very basic thigns

Comment: What language do you use? Search for "mylang watch restart on save" or something. `cargo-watch` for Rust, `tsx` for typescript, `nodemon`/`chokidar` for javascript (tsx also works and better)

Comment: i'm just modifying json file in vscode

Comment: are you using Dart/Flutter? Because if so, I wager this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49210769/11107541

Comment: well, I've tried that as well
But the issue is i don't want to run from "Run Without debugging" or "Start Debugging" from "Run" tab cause it disconnects multiple times and I want to maximize my productivity, so I'll opt terminal that's why I want to send 'r' to terminal

Comment: Just done with it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to pass the args to a specific command while using mutliple commands

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+s",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                "args": {
                    "text": "r"
                }
            },
            "workbench.action.files.save"
        ], 
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```